# How to perform a table UNION in SubSonic

Tags: subsonic

I have a query that performs a UNION between two tables. I'm trying to implement the same thing with SubSonic. I have two related questions:

- What is the SubSonic syntax to perform a union.
- How do I rename a column. Assuming the UNION will require to match the column names between the two tables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a UNION syntax in SubSonic. You could use an inline query as dicussed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090321074429/http://forums.subsonicproject.com/forums/t/3684.aspx) e.g.

```
MyTableCollection MyTable = new InlineQuery().ExecuteAsCollection<MyTableCollection>(
    “SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM TableA Union SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM TableB");
```

The best solution I've found is to implement the UNION inside a view and then get SubSonic to generate a model for that view instead.

Comment: @Aristos Fixed the link so it gets a cache from archive.org